# How to show dialog in activity from service?

Tags: android, service, dialog

I'm developing an app that downloads some data in service and show it via push-notifications, also user can read other data in activity. So could you explain me how can i make a dilalog that's show's to user when WIFI/3G is turned off and says something like this "For normally app working you should turn 3G/WIFI on". A problem is that i must implemet it by service callback, i.e. by this logic:

service start downloading data --> No internet --> Cheks if WiFi/3G is turned off --> Shows in any Activity a Dialog.

I know that i can make it by using a receiver, but how a can call a dialog in every activity? Or i don't need an activity, just a context in OnReceive method, right? Please give me any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or i don't need an activity, just a context in OnReceive method, right?

No, that is incorrect. A `Dialog` needs an `Activity`. You could show a `Toast` from `onReceive()` using the `Context` that it has.

Or, as Junior was suggesting, you can create an `Activity` with a `Dialog theme`. To do this, you simply need to add the following line to the `<activity>` tag in your `manifest.xml` for the appropriate `Activity`

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

This is nice because it gives you all the functionality of an `Activity` while displaying as a `Dialog` so the user doesn't feel like they have "left" where they are.

Comment: yeap this nice, but it will override my custom app-style. What are you thinking about this - create an parent activity which contains a broadcastReceiver and method that shows a dialog if activity is on screen righ now and all activities set to inherit of that parent activity.

Comment: You can create a separate `Activity` with this `Theme` to call when you need. You can set the `layout` for it to have your custom `styles`

Comment: and this Activity will be showed always while service is running, right? I think it is bad idea, cause my service is STICKY and this activity will annoy the user. I must show a dialog only when any activity is alive

Comment: It will be shown until you call `finish()` on it like any other `Activity`. I guess I don't understand what you are after then.

Comment: mb i've misunderstood you too, ok,let me explain - you've offer me to use a separate Activity with Theme.Dialog which will be called from my service by Intent(this, DialogActivity.class), did i get it right? But what i'm talking to you that my service will be call this activity every time while it's running(and WiFi/3G is turned off) and even when app is closed, right?. I think that is wrong, cause it will disturb and annoy the user when he doesnt use an app right now.

Comment: Then only start it if your app is running. [See this answer for checking if your app is running](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F15085897%2Fcheck-if-my-app-is-running-in-android&ei=G9KtUrfIGorIyAHtxYCQAw&usg=AFQjCNFVxZ-i3XonuLl3cGCTYXo3UhwF3g&sig2=sPEaiIH4D88H4b1PAsvX0w&bvm=bv.57967247,d.aWc)

Answer (score 0):

Launch an activity (of your own) with a dialog theme.

Hope it helps!

Comment: What do you mean "Launch an activity with a dialog theme"? I didn't get it.

Comment: You should set the style of the activity to that of a dialog. You cannot start a dialog from a service. It will be like an activity but with the look n' feel of a dialog. There are system defined themes such as Theme.Dialog (check for Holo styles on modern platforms) that can serve for this purpose. Regards.

Comment: Unfortunately, it'll override my custom app style.

Comment: No, it won't. You shouldn't override the whole app style but only that of the activity that will look like a dialog.

Comment: You can also set Theme.Dialog or Theme.Holo.Dialog as the parent of your activity style and customize a theme so you don't loose the look n' feel. It's up to you to decide whether to use a system theme or to inflate a layout that looks like the dialog you want to display. Remember you have the full power of Activity.